# URL route from Laravel to Vue Router

Tags: laravel, vue-router

I'm using `Laravel 5.4` and `vue-js 2.4`

#### Laravel routes

```php
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@home');
```

#### HomeController

```php
public function home(Request $request) {
   return view('app');
}
```

#### Vue router

```js
const routes = [
    { path: '/', name: 'home', component: App},
    { path: '/about', component: About },
];
```

When I click on this, `about` component is well displayed and the url is `example.com/about`

```html
<router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
```

#### Issue

When I enter `example.com/about`, I'm redirected to the home page of my vue app which is `example.com`.

What should I do so the `about` can reach `vue-router` ?

Comment: Do you have any other Laravel routes registered? Why aren't you getting a 404 when visiting `/about`?

Comment: Yes I have a lot but nothing `/about`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Route::get('/{component?}', 'HomeController@home');`

Seems to be working

Comment: How does that work? What does the controller look like?

Comment: You need to create a catch-all route. To check what the controller looks like just go to my first post. The home function just return the view app in which the vuejs app is mounted

Answer (score 0):

Add a route to your `about` page on laravel just like `/` route:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@home');
Route::get('/about', 'HomeController@home');
```